# Treeviewr rcp application

Tags: eclipse, treeview, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to create my own RCP application but I have a problem: when I try to create a new project I need to create a folder2 under folder1

```java
 else if (name.equals(NEWCHILD)) {
            NewChildWizard childwiz = (NewChildWizard) page;
            tree.addChild(childwiz.getParentName(), childwiz.getChildName());

            IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
            IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();

            String namee = ((NewChildWizard) page).getParentName();
            String name2 = ((NewChildWizard) page).getChildName();
            IProject project = root.getProject(namee);
            IProject project2 = root.getProject(name2);

            try {
                project.create(new NullProgressMonitor());
                project2.create(new NullProgressMonitor());
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                project.open(new NullProgressMonitor());
                project2.open(new NullProgressMonitor());
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

someone can help me ??? thanks in advance

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I need to create a tree viewr lik this  http://www.google.tn/imgres?imgurl=http://www.techjava.de/wp-content/uploads/rcp_cnf.png&imgrefurl=http://www.techjava.de/topics/2009/04/eclipse-common-navigator-framework/&h=302&w=402&tbnid=PVme66_gG8cWlM:&zoom=1&docid=_m3ajUrX572IiM&ei=SyA2VdvNCeOHygO3mICwAQ&tbm=isch&ved=0CFkQMyg1MDU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a folder in a project do something like:

```java
IFolder folder = project.getFolder(new Path("folder name"));

if (!folder.exists())
 {
   folder.create(false, true, progressMonitor);  
 }
```